# PackageManager.checkPermission Delivers Sometimes Incorrect Results

Tags: android, permissions

`PackageManager.checkPermission` delivers sometimes incorrect results.

As an example, I disabled both permissions (as you can see in the picture), but `checkPermission` returns always `True`.

Applied to other apps, it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.

[image]

Edit:

```
getPackageManager().checkPermission("android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",packageName) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
```

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: @JuanCruzSoler The Code is in the Question now